# Repopulate checkbox fields in the form after validation in laravel 5

Tags: validation, checkbox, laravel-5.4

I was trying to repopulate the checkbox fields after the validation in Laravel. Actually the checkbox fields name as an array. Example:

```
<form name="" action="" method="post">
<div class="row>
   <input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="1">Model 1
   <input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="2">Model 2
   <input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="3">Model 3
   <input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="4">Model 4
   <input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="5">Model 5
</div>
<div class="row>
   <input type="checkbox" name="model_name" value="" placeholder="Model Name">       
</div>
<div class="row>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

My form will look like this. So after submitting the form there will be a validation error and i need to repopulate the check box value after the validation error. I have already tried with {{ old('field_name') }} to make the checkbox as checked. But it is not working. Anyone have the solution for this to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried similar to the below code in Laravel 5.5

```
<input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="1" @if( is_array(old('models')) && in_array(1, old('models'))) checked @endif  >Model 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close! You just need to 'reactivate' the checked modus by putting the word 'checked' in the `<input>` element if the old value of `model_name` is detected.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="model_name" value="" placeholder="Model Name">
       @if (old('model_name'))
           checked
       @endif
/>
```

Comment: But the checkbox name is defined as array. will this work for it?

Comment: Forgot about your array, sorry! Let me think for a second. For your last input element it will work though.

Comment: I can't think of a 100% correct solution right now, but a possible way is to check in your PHP if the 'models' array is set, and then return the value or name of each checked model back to the view. There you check for the existence of the value that you received in PHP and add the attribute 'checked' in that 'input' element. Hope it is a bit clearer. As said, my solution will work for your last input element (name='model_name'), but sorry that I can't help you further with the array (other than providing a possible approach).

Comment: thanks for your idea. But the thing is that i am using the laravel framework for the development. So after the validation error i am returning to the page by using the following code.


if ($validator->fails()) {  
          return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
            }

Comment: You're welcome, it's the least I could try! One thing I can advise in addition to your last response is that you can add '->with($array_with_variables)' to that returning request. And that array could contain the data that you checked. Whenever you use the '->with($some_variable)' in such a request, the data of $some_variable will be available to you in the view.

Comment: That's great. Let me try something like that way. I will update you if there is any progress on the issue

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me (Laravel 5.2)

```
@foreach ($models as $model)
    <input type="checkbox" name="models[{{ $model->id }}]"
        @if (is_array(old('models')) && in_array($model->id, array_keys(old('models'))))
            checked
        @endif
    > {{ $model->name }}
@endforeach
```